# How to centrally align 1/3 width columns using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I centrally align 2 columns taking up 1/3 of the width in bootstrap? I tried searching Google and have found solutions with 3 columns but I need 2.

Thanks for your answers

**HTML**

```
<div class="row circles">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-circle"></div>
        <strong>Loren ipsum</strong>
        <div class="text">Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-circle"></div>
        <strong>Loren ipsum</strong>
        <div class="text">Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul.circles {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px auto 0px;
}
ul.circles p {
    text-align: center;
}
ul.circles .text,strong {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px;
}
.img-circle {
    background-color: #2d0e1e;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here's an image for example:

[image: Example of what I need]

Answer (score 2):

You could offset your first column, using the `col-lg-offset-2` and `col-md-offset-2` classes:

```
<div class="row circles">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="img-circle"></div>
    <strong>Loren ipsum</strong>
    <div class="text">Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="img-circle"></div>
    <strong>Loren ipsum</strong>
    <div class="text">Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og Og at proﬁlen gir et solid og </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: In this particular case, your `col-md-*` classes are redundant and can be removed.

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/mQ51DC289d)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but in your CSS you could use the following:

```
.row.circles {margin: 0px auto;}
```

Would that work?

Comment: What css code do you have for the classes .row and .circles?